# Noobie Jquery mobile js

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

im quite new at js and jqm. So I have a basic script that opens a panel when I scroll the the side. I use #panel on all of the pages however the script will only work for the first page. Whats the best way to make this work for ever page? Do I have to include it at the end of every page? Should I individually name each panel and do ("#panel, #panel2") etc.

```
<script>
$( document ).on( "pageinit", document, function() {
    $( document ).on( "swipeleft", document, function( e ) {

        if ( $.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
            if ( e.type === "swipeleft"  ) {
               $( "#mypanel" ).panel( "open" );
            }
        }
    });
});    
</script>
```

Comment: did you try try with a class ? (".panel) ..instead than id..

Comment: and yeah I d put the sript on every page..unless you have a JS loaded from all ur pages in that case put the script in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$.mobile.activePage.find('#id').panel('open')` if you are using the same panel *id* for all pages. Also, you should add panel to each page.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/nmmuj/)**

```
$(document).on("swipeleft", '[data-role=page]', function (e) {
  if (!$.mobile.activePage.hasClass('ui-page-panel-open') && e.type == "swipeleft") {
    $.mobile.activePage.find("#panel").panel("open");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try that :

```
$( document ).on( "swipeleft", $.mobile.activePage, function( e )
```